# Uncaught-TypeError-Cannot-call-method-substring-of-undefined-sencha-touch-all.js

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, sencha-touch

I am a new to Sencha Touch, though I have little knowledge about MVC, I am getting an error while I try to build an application following the video tutorial of Sencha Touch 2 as:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined
>   sencha-touch-all.js:35

The code is as follows:

app.js:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true


});
Ext.application({
    name: 'SBR',
    controllers: [
        'Main'
    ],
    launch: function(){
        Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel',{
            fullscreen: true,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'homepanel'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'carousel',
                title: 'Blog',
                iconCls: 'star',
                html: 'Student Blog',
                items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'image',
                    src: 'resources/images/icon1.png'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'image',
                    src: 'resources/images/icon2.png'
                }]

            },
            {

                title: 'Enter your Comments',
                iconCls: 'star',
                html: 'Enter your Comments'
            }

            ]

        });
    }
});
```

Home.js - the View

```
Ext.define('SBR.view.Home', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'homepanel',
    config:{
        title: 'Home',
        iconCls: 'home',
        html: 'Html through View'
    }
});
```

Main.js - The Controller

```
Ext.define('SBR.controller.Main',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views: ['Home'],
    init: function(){
        console.log('It is tested - Ok');
    }
});
```

If the code of the view (Home.js) is set in the app.js without using a xtype, it works fine, but when I define a view and try to access the view by xtype from app.js it does not work and throws the above exception, although it logs the message passed in the controller successfully in the console.

Browser Used : Chrome

IDE : Aptana

Sencha Touch Version: 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add all the View, Store and Model classes in app.js just the same way you added the controller:

```
controllers: [
        'Main'
],
views : [
    'Home'
]
```

This should make it work.